# Unterschied zwischen »zanken« und »streiten«

Tags: difference, meaning

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *zanken* und *streiten*? Oder *Zank* und *Streit*? Der Duden erklärt jeweils das eine Wort mit dem anderen (abgesehen von Nebenbedeutungen):

***[zanken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zanken)***

> 1. mit jemandem einen Zank haben, sich mit jemandem **streiten**

***[Zank](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zank)***

> mit gegenseitigen Beschimpfungen, Vorwürfen, Gehässigkeiten ausgetragener **Streit** (meist aus einem geringfügigen Anlass)

***[streiten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/streiten)***

> 2. mit jemandem Streit haben, in Streit geraten; sich mit jemandem in oft hitzigen Wortwechseln, oft auch in Handgreiflichkeiten heftig auseinandersetzen; sich **zanken**

***[Streit](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Streit)***

> heftiges Sichauseinandersetzen, **Zanken** [mit einem persönlichen Gegner] in oft erregten Erörterungen, hitzigen Wortwechseln, oft auch in Handgreiflichkeiten

Comment: This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or provide more context.

Comment: @jor - solche Beispiele wird es immer geben, da wir zu diesem Thema keine starre Regeln möchten. Siehe dazu http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/915/please-vote-on-another-approach-to-close-reasons und http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/698/research-effort-revisited. Allerdings sind wir uns einig, dass solche Fragen die Ausnahme bleiben müssen. Wir können und wollen keine Sammlung von Wörterbucheinträgen werden und wir sind auch kein Thesaurus, dafür ist das Stack-Exchange-Modell ungeeignet.

Answer (score 2):

Während *Streit* das ganze Spektrum von Auseinandersetzungen umfasst mit größerem Gewicht auf Wortwechseln und Diskussionen, ist mit *Zank* in der Regel die verschärfte Form von Streit gemeint, bei der Tätlichkeiten oder deren Vorstufe (Gemeinheiten, verletzende verbale Angriffe usw.) dazukommen. Die Grenzen verschwimmen oft, die Schwerpunkte liegen aber eindeutig unterschiedlich.<sup>([1](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GZ00978#XGZ00978))</sup>

Die Verwendung von *Zank* beschränkt sich heutzutage auf die Alltagssprache, evtl. auch noch regional beschränkt. Auf gehobenerer Sprachebene verwendet man den Begriff *Streit*.

Comment: Deswegen auch Streitkräfte. ;)

Comment: Vornehm geht die Welt zugrunde

Comment: Man könnte noch anfügen, daß 'Zank' und 'zanken' eine klar negative konnotation haben

Answer (score 2):

Während *Streiten* eine durchaus konstruktive Sache sein kann (im Sinne beispielsweise einer Streitdiskussion) fehlt *Zanken* dieser konstruktive Aspekt.

Beide bezeichnen in der Regel eine Meinungsverschiedenheit, beschreiben aber eine unterschiedliche Qualität.

*Streit* ist auch der umfassendere Begriff. Er beinhaltet sowohl "niederen Zank" als auch "hochwertige Diskussion", beispielsweise auch Wettstreit.

Answer (score 1):

Nur Kinder zanken sich. Im täglichen Sprachgebrauch wird `Zank` nur verwendet um anzudeuten dass sich die Auseinandersetzung auf einer kindischen Ebene bewegt.

Comment: Was ist mit zänkischen Weibern?

Answer (score 1):

Um auszudrücken, dass zwei Personen eine verbale Auseinandersetzung führen oder eine aktive feindselige Beziehung zueinander haben kann man beide Begriffspaare synonym verwenden, wobei `Streit/streiten` im Hochdeutschen gebräuchlicher ist.

Aber man findet leicht Beispiele, wo das nicht funktioniert:

> für eine Sache streiten / für eine Sache zanken

oder

> willst du mich zanken? / willst du mich streiten?

oder

> Rechtsstreit, Ehestreit, Tarifstreit / Rechtszank, Ehezank, Tarifzank

oder

> darüber streiten sich die Experten / darüber zanken sich die Experten

oder

> suchst du Streit? / suchst du Zank?

Wie man sieht, hat `Streit/streiten` auch die Bedeutung von `Kampf/kämpfen`, die `Zank/zanken` nicht hat. Daher wird `Zank/zanken` vielleicht je nach Kontext eher so verstanden werden, dass eine Auseinandersetzung harmlos oder nicht ernstzunehmen ist.

`zanken` hat dafür eine Bedeutung von `ärgern/reizen/provozieren`, die `streiten` fehlt. Darum würde ich nach meinem persönlichen Sprachgefühl den Satz

> Das gibt Zank.

auch eher verstehen als "Das wird für Unzufriedenheit sorgen.", während

> Das gibt Streit.

für mich bedeutet, dass eine Auseinandersetzung oder Eskalation bevorsteht.

Aber während es relativ klar ist, wo die beiden Wortpaare nicht synonym sind, bezweifle ich, dass man in dem Bereich, wo sich die Bedeutungen überschneiden, eine objektive Aussage machen kann, wo genau die Unterschiede liegen.

Answer (score 0):

"Streiten" ist heute das geläufige Wort. "zanken" dürfte heute mehr regionaler Gebrauch sein, aber ob jemand zu Kindern sagt "Was zankt/streitet ihr denn schon wieder?" kann auch individueller Sprachgebrauch sein. Dennoch findet man Wörter wie Zank, zanken, Gezänk, zänkisch in geschriebener Sprache immer wieder mal.